# MySQL Query to get name and contact of persons from DINERS on specific DINING_TABLE

Tags: mysql, sql, database, nested

I have a scenario where different chefs offer their `dining_tables` for `booking` (maximum four diners at single table). Different diners check if a seat is available with any chef.

I have three different tables such that:

- `basic_profile` contains the data of all the users (name, contact, age etc)
- `register_diner` contains details of a dining table (offered_by(chef), chair_1...chair_4, ...)

When a diner checks that a chair is available in a chefs `dining_table`, he click the book button and his email is stored under `chair_1/2/3/4` which ever he choose.

now for the chef to see that who has registered with him, he can query like

```
select * from register_diner where offered_by = 'ME'.
```

He/she gets results like

```
offered_by, chair_1, chair_2, chair_3, chair_4 ....  
ME,         a@b.com  x@y.com   i@j.com  b@c.com
```

Now I want to run a query which can show me the name and contact of a person from `basic_profile`, at `chair 1/2/3/4` instead of email. For other tables I used nested queries, but here I have four keywords and I have done all I could for the past three days to achieve it.

Need help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, your application should input IDs and not emails into `register_diner` for each of the four chairs. But to return corresponding name and contact, consider multiple self-joins to the `basic_profile` lookup table. Below assumes there is an `email` field in `basic_profile`:

```
select r.offered_by
       , p1.name as chair1_name, p1.contact as chair1_contact
       , p2.name as chair2_name, p2.contact as chair2_contact
       , p3.name as chair3_name, p3.contact as chair3_contact
       , p4.name as chair4_name, p4.contact as chair4_contact
from register_diner r
inner join basic_profile p1
   on r.chair1 = p1.email
inner join basic_profile p2
   on r.chair2 = p2.email
inner join basic_profile p3
   on r.chair3 = p3.email
inner join basic_profile p4
   on r.chair4 = p4.email
where r.offered_by = 'ME'
```

But once again, ideally you join by IDs which would be much more efficient than potentially long `text` or `varchar` fields:

```
inner join basic_profile p1
   on r.chair1_profile_id = p1.id
...
```

In fact, best practice in database design suggests you should normalize your table from wide to long format since in future, you may raise larger tables to 5 or 6. It is less expensive and more manageable to add rows than columns. Then, you just need one `join` to lookup table with new column for chair number.

```
select r.offered_by
       , r.chair_number
       , p.name as chair_name
       , p.contact as chair_contact
from register_diner r
inner join basic_profile p
   on r.profile_id = p.id
```

Comment: i got some idea from your answer, however, the email fields in profile are non-duplicate and are distinct. So i am using them as an id instead. Since i am not expert in Databases, i am sure what you said will be right.

Comment: Understood. Did first block resolve your original problem? And yes, integer fields in primary/foreign keys for one-to-many related tables is the more efficient setup instead of varchar/text fields like *email*.

Comment: i am trying to understand the self joins at the moment, i dont want to copy paste and change it. i want to learn first then implement.

Comment: Ah, yes! I fixed that small omission. Glad solution worked. Happy coding!